# Custom experience editor button in Horizon

Tags: horizon

I've added a custom experience button to a component to be able to edit the data - it's a component showing an external video so the editors needs to be able to set the url. This works fine in the Experience Editor. However, we would like to use Horizon and in that editing environment those experience buttons are not shown.

If I manage to click exactly on the border of the component I get the component details and am able to click through to a content view of the datasource and edit the url. But for most editors, this is rather difficult.

So my question is actually: how can I enable my editors to edit such a video component in Horizon?